# Google Optimize AB Test variant preview not showing

Tags: google-optimize, abtest

I have problens sharing my AB tests. I see the Variants working on Chrome, but if I use for example Incognito mode or Firefox it does not show. I have tested using the share preview links and even logging in on these browsers and launching the preview from the Test page.
For example, here is a simple console log. The left is Chrome incognito and the right is regular Chrome. I've traced the console log code (the function inserted by GO) and it just shows in regular Chrome.
Any idea what is going wrong?
Thanks[image: Variant bug]

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable third party cookie blocking while browsing incognito mode:
[image]

Comment: Correct. Also I find [this](https://akohubteam.medium.com/how-to-enable-third-party-cookies-on-your-browsers-f9a8143b8cc5#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Safari%20drop,'%20select%20the%20option%20'Never.) and it can help as well